# Unable to get list of files in workspace developing VS Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying out creating a VS Code Extension and want to get a list of files in the current workspace.

I've created an extension using `yo`, following the [Hello World](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) documentation.

I am trying to get the list of files in the current workspace with the following code:

```
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.removeConsoleLogs', async () => {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
        const files = await vscode.workspace.findFiles('**.*.*', '**/node_modules/**');

        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('number of files',files.length.toString());
        files.forEach(file => {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello VS Code!!!!!');

        });
        // Display a message box to the user

    });
```

> When I open a folder with files in it in the VS Code developer and then run the extension `number of files 0` is output

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just fix the include GlobPattern match pattern.

```
    const files = await vscode.workspace.findFiles('**/*.*', '**/node_modules/**');
```